# Read data from ul into a different ul

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to read out my navbar, and then put this in another `ul` using jQuery.

Not sure how to do it. I tried using `.each` & `.children`.

Reading from my navigation (this list):

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="materiaal.html">Materiaal</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="muziek.html">Muziek</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="mixing1.html">Mixing Pt. 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="mixing2.html">Mixing Pt. 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="performing.html">Performing</a></li>
</ul>
```

Putting them in this list:

```
<ul class="navigatie"></ul>
```

Comment: I can't fully understand your question. Please can you show an exact before and after for this example to help explain some more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to deal with the elements individually. You can `clone()` the whole batch and `append()` the result to the other `ul`:

```js
$('.navbar-nav > li').clone().appendTo('.navigatie')
```

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="materiaal.html">Materiaal</a></li>
  <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="muziek.html">Muziek</a></li>
  <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="mixing1.html">Mixing Pt. 1</a></li>
  <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="mixing2.html">Mixing Pt. 2</a></li>
  <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="performing.html">Performing</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="navigatie"></ul>
```

Comment: Is this also like traversing? Since it's for a school project, that's why i went with each. Didn't really find any other use for traversing on my site.

Comment: jQuery is traversing the nodes for you. If you must, you could use `each()`, and within the inner `each` function use `$(this).clone().appendTo('.navigatie');`

Comment: So then the whole jquery would be like this?

$('.navbar-nav').each(function() {
                    $(this).clone().appendTo('.navigatie')
                });

Comment: Nope. That will clone the whole `ul`. You want the `li` elements *inside* it. Look at my sample code above.

Comment: `$('.navbar-nav > li').each(  function() { $(this).clone().appendTo('.navigatie'); } );`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to get the content of ul.

Try this:

```js
 $(".navigatie").html($(".navbar-nav").html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="materiaal.html">Materiaal</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="muziek.html">Muziek</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="mixing1.html">Mixing Pt. 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="mixing2.html">Mixing Pt. 2</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="performing.html">Performing</a></li>
        </ul>
        <br><br>
        <ul class="navigatie"></ul>
```